How to control ArCore camera's focus while in FocusMode.FIXED
I have a very specific task with ArCore and if someone had a similar situation, here is the use case: I have to use ArCore session’s FIXED focus (not AUTO). But then whenever the user clicks to refocus, it has to adjust the focus to whatever the user is looking at and keep the focus at that distance until next refocus click.
I tried few things, searching for the low level code but there is only the SDK repository, the low level part is available in *.so format only… Additionally, I don’t know how to use camera2 or cameraX api in sync with ArCore, or if it’s even possible…
So the question is, does someone know if the low level ArCore library source code is available anywhere or if there is a workaround/hack to control the camera focus while ArCore's session is active?
